# Retrieving child record when parent key is unknown in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have a data like this:

```
"customers": {
    "aHh4OTQ2NTlAa2xvYXAuY29t": {
        "customerId": "xxx",
        "name": "yyy",
        "subscription": "zzz"
    }
}
```

I need to retrive a customer by customerId. The parent key is just B64 encoded mail address due to path limitations. Usually I am querying data by this email address, but for a few occasions I know only customerId. I've tried this:

```
getCustomersRef()
   .orderByChild('customerId')
   .equalTo(customerId)
   .limitToFirst(1)
   .once('child_added', cb);
```

This works nicely in case the customer really exists. In opposite case the callback is never called.

I tried `value` event which works, but that gives me whole tree starting with encoded email address so I cannot reach the actual data inside. Or can I?

I have found this answer [Test if a data exist in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24824732/test-if-a-data-exist-in-firebase), but that again assumes that you I know all path elements.

```
getCustomersRef().once('value', (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.hasChild(`customerId/${customerId}`);
});
```

What else I can do here ?

**Update**

I think I found solution, but it doesn't feel right.

```
let found = null;
snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
    found = childSnapshot.val();
});
return found;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to query firebase for property with specific value inside all children](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272919/how-to-query-firebase-for-property-with-specific-value-inside-all-children)

Comment: Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14965065/1300910) answer might help you

Comment: Can you clarify the question? It states you want to 'retrieve a child record when parent key is unknown'. That's what a firebase query does - it 'looks' through a set of nodes to see if any of them has a child matching the data you specify - the parent node doesn't need to be specified, only the node that is the parent of the nodes that contain the child you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**old; misunderstood the question :**

> If you know the "endcodedB64Email", this is the way.:

```
var endcodedB64Email = B64_encoded_mail_address;

firebase.database().ref(`customers/${endcodedB64Email}`).once("value").then(snapshot => {
       // this is getting your customerId/uid. Remember to set your rules up for your database for security! Check out tutorials on YouTube/Firebase's channel.
       var uid = snapshot.val().customerId;
       console.log(uid) // would return 'xxx' from looking at your database

// you want to check with '.hasChild()'? If you type in e.g. 'snapshot.hasChild(`customerId`)' then this would return true, because 'customerId' exists in your database if I am not wrong ...
});
```

> **UPDATE (correction) :**
>
> We have to know at least one key. So if you under some circumstances
>   only know the **customer-uid-key**, then I would do it like this.:

```
// this is the customer-uid-key that is know. 
var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid; // this fetches the user-id, referring to the current user logged in with the firebase-login-function
// this is the "B64EmailKey" that we will find if there is a match in the firebase-database
var B64EmailUserKey = undefined;

// "take a picture" of alle the values under the key "customers" in the Firebase database-JSON-object
firebase.database().ref("customers").once("value").then(snapshot => {
     // this counter-variable is used to know when the last key in the "customers"-object is passed
     var i = 0;
     // run a loop on all values under "customers". "B64EmailKey" is a parameter. This parameter stores data; in this case the value for the current "snapshot"-value getting caught
     snapshot.forEach(B64EmailKey => {
          // increase the counter by 1 every time a new key is run
          i++;
          // this variable defines the value (an object in this case)
          var B64EmailKey_value = B64EmailKey.val();
          // if there is a match for "customerId" under any of the "B64EmailKey"-keys, then we have found the corresponding correct email linked to that uid
          if (B64EmailKey_value.customerId === uid) {
               // save the "B64EmailKey"-value/key and quit the function
               B64EmailUserKey = B64EmailKey_value.customerId;

               return B64UserKeyAction(B64EmailUserKey)
          }

          // if no linked "B64EmailUserKey" was found to the "uid"
          if (i === Object.keys(snapshot).length) {
               // the last key (B64EmailKey) under "customers" was returned. e.g. no "B64EmailUserKey" linkage to the "uid" was found
               return console.log("Could not find an email linked to your account.")
          }
     });
});

 // run your corresponding actions here
 function B64UserKeyAction (emailEncrypted) {
      return console.log(`The email-key for user: ${auth.currentUser.uid} is ${emailEncrypted}`)
 }
```

> I recommend putting this in a function or class, so you can easily call it up and reuse the code in an organized way.

**I also** want to add that the rules for your firebase must be defined to make everything secure. And if sensitive data must be calculated (e.g. price), then do this on server-side of Firebase! Use Cloud Functions. This is new for Firebase 2017.

Comment: It's little bit old question, I don't remember how I solved it, but as I said above "but for a few occasions I know only customerId". Your solution is expecting that endcodedB64Email is known, which isn't.

Comment: Hello. Sorry about that. I have now updated the answer for how to get the right 'endcodedB64Email' if you only know the 'customerId'. Tell me if this was what you though of.

Comment: Thanks, but this must have awful memory footprint essentially loading all customers (till correct one is found). I guess that best way, in the end, would be to have a separate lookup map with customeri->email.

Comment: Yes, definitely uses more memory. Firebase encourages to denormalize data allot in the database. To use a separate lookup like you mentioned `customerId => email` would be the best! Simple code like e.g. `firebase.database().ref("users/" + auth.currentUser.uid).once("value").then(snap => {var email = snap.val().email});`

Comment: I do think it is OK to do it in this way if you have to. If I am not wrong, Firebase is built to do this kind of data-handling. Your dataplan might go up though. This example encourages people to do this if needed.
 [firebase.docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events)