# Firebase Query Double Nested

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Given the data structure below in firebase, i want to run a query to retrieve the blog 'efg'.  I don't know the user id at this point.

```
{Users :
     "1234567": {
          name: 'Bob',
          blogs: {
               'abc':{..},
               'zyx':{..}
          }
     },
     "7654321": {
          name: 'Frank',
          blogs: {
               'efg':{..},
               'hij':{..}
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24869180/query-hierarchical-data-structure-in-firebase

Comment: There's really no reason to have blogs as a part of the users' records. They aren't a logical "attribute" of a user, they are a separate entity with their own data structures, purpose, and read/write scenarios. I'd start by splitting those (as Frank mentioned) and making things simple and direct.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The Firebase API only allows you to filter children one level deep (or [with a known path](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-09-24-atomic-writes-and-more.html)) with its `orderByChild` and `equalTo` methods.

So without modifying/expanding your current data structure that just leaves the option to retrieve all data and filter it client-side:

```js
var ref = firebase.database().ref('Users');
ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(userSnapshot) {
        var blogs = userSnapshot.val().blogs;
        var daBlog = blogs['efg'];
    });
});
```

This is of course highly inefficient and won't scale when you have a non-trivial number of users/blogs.

So the common solution to that is to a so-called index to your tree that maps the key that you are looking for to the path where it resides:

```js
{Blogs:
     "abc": "1234567",
     "zyx": "1234567",
     "efg": "7654321",
     "hij": "7654321"
}
```

Then you can quickly access the blog using:

```js
var ref = firebase.database().ref();
ref.child('Blogs/efg').once('value', function(snapshot) {
    var user = snapshot.val();
    ref.child('Blogs/'+user+'/blogs').once('value', function(blogSnapshot) {
        var daBlog = blogSnapshot.val();
    });
});
```

You might also want to reconsider if you can restructure your data to better fit your use-case and Firebase's limitations. They have some good documentation on structuring your data, but the most important one for people new to NoSQL/hierarchical databases seems to be ["avoid building nests"](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html#section-denormalizing-data).

Also see my answer on [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value) for a good example. I'd also recommend reading about [many-to-many relationships in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527058/many-to-many-relationship-in-firebase), and this article on general [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).

Comment: Note that [deep queries](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-09-24-atomic-writes-and-more.html) are now a feature.

Comment: I've thought about it for a few minutes, but give up: how would a deep query solve this problem?

Comment: I don't think a deep query solves the problem; but the post states that you can only query one-level deep, which is no longer true.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I've been reading a lot of your answers lately (you seem to be the only one who knows anything about firebase [seeing as how you're a firebase engineer]) and I'm wondering if you final solution in your answer is a best practice, or should we always try to make the information structured so that we may make only a single call?

Answer (score 2):

Given your current data structure you can retrieve the User that contains the blog post you are looking for.

```
const db = firebase.database()
const usersRef = db.ref('users')
const query = usersRef.orderByChild('blogs/efg').limitToLast(1)
query.once('value').then((ss) => {
  console.log(ss.val()) //=> { '7654321': { blogs: {...}}}
})
```

You need to use `limitToLast` since Objects are sorted last when using `orderByChild` [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#data-order).

Answer (score 1):

It's actually super easy - just use foreslash:

```
db.ref('Users').child("userid/name")
db.ref('Users').child("userid/blogs")
db.ref('Users').child("userid/blogs/abc")
```

No need of loops or anything more.