# Query in firebase

Tags: firebase

Need help with firebase query. In firebase how to query element which are two level down.

```
{
 Father : {
   Child : {
     Grand-child: {
        "a" : "some  value",
        "email" : "user email id "
      }
}}}
```

Under Father there are many Child elements

### Under each Child  there are many Grand-children .. I would like to select all the Grand-children have email starting with "abc".. How to do that.. Basically want to select grand-child regardless of the parent for that particular element.. Appreciate any help..

Editing the question : I couldn't find the functionality in documentation.. In Jquery world it may look like this..

```
 <div id='top'>
    <div>
        <a href='#'> Second level child 1 </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href='#'> Second level child 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
$( "#top>*>a" ).on('click', function () {
alert("here")
return true;
});
```

Do we have something similar in firebase, so fetch what selector is doing in jquery. Appreciate you help..

Comment: What did you try already? Please edit your question and show the code of what you've already tried.

Comment: Hi Frank.. just edited the question with jquery sample.. Not sure whether we have something similar in firebase, which can help us fetch 2 level (down) elements ignoring what is in between..

Comment: In Firebase you can do `new Firebase('https://your.firebaseio.com/Father/Child/Grand-child').on('value', ...` to only get the grand-children. It's documented (a.o.) on https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html

Comment: Are you suggesting to iterate through each result and throw whichever I don't need.. I need all the grand children having age 10(say).. regardless of their father :-).. I was expecting syntax like https://your.firebaseio.com/Father/*/Grand-child ... not sure whether it is possible.. can you please elaborate

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24869180/query-hierarchical-data-structure-in-firebase

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would indeed need to iterate through all fathers and children. You can query children with Firebase's new queries, but not children of children. Below is an example for acting on grandchildren that are 10 years old.

```
var fathersRef = new Firebase('https://your.firebaseio.com');

fathersRef.on('child_added', function(fatherSnap) {
  fatherSnap.ref().on('child_added', function(childSnap) {
    childSnap.ref().orderByChild('age').equalTo(10).on('child_added', function(grandchildSnap) {

      \\ Do something with the grandchild
      var grandChild = grandchildSnap.val();

    });
  });
});
```